# Django url error when GET request with params,

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Django API to export file which needs **format** as input,

```
Request URL: http://192.168.5.51:1212/rest/tasks/export_file/CIAYEK5W5JS4MdmCF2t8eB?format=xyz
```

this request returns a error response

```
detail (with status 404)
```

but when I use get request without query params,

```
Request URL: http://192.168.5.51:1212/rest/tasks/export_file/CIAYEK5W5JS4MdmCF2t8eB
```

The API is triggered and the file is returned(with default format). As far as i know we don't need to change anything in urlpatterns to support query params. I have also put the specified url in first line to eliminate the chance for any other regex catching the request

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^/export_file/(?P<pk>.+)$',views.TaskFileTranscript.as_view()),
```

How to support query params in django requests. Thank you in advance.

P.S : Im pretty sure the control is not reaching into the get function, Im using DRF.

Answer (score 0):

you have to customize it yourself for example in a class-based view get method:

```
class Test(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        formatQuery = request.GET.get('format', None)
        # use this format to customize your result
        return Response(result)
```

and also add / to end of your URL:

```
http://192.168.5.51:1212/rest/tasks/export_file/CIAYEK5W5JS4MdmCF2t8eB/?format=xyz
```

Comment: yes, i did customize it myself, but the control is not even reaching to 'def get(self,request)'. and also tried / to end of my url , not working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone, it is fixed now. got to know its really a bad idea to use 'format' as query param key.